# Bootstrap4-styled <select> element rendering incorrectly

Tags: html, css, browser, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap and `<select>` elements on my page without any additional styling and wonder why their arrows look ugly.

That's how a Bootstrap4-styled `<select>` shows in Firefox (not much difference in Chrome either):

[image]

And this is how Firefox normally renders a `<select>` element without Bootstrap:

[image]

It seems that those selects are affected that are parts of a Bootstrap *input-group*, as [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0043ozj4/1/) shows.

What causes this issue and is there any solution to get the default look back?

Comment: do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Looks like a browser bug to me ... going through the styles in developer tools and disabling a bunch of them seems to make the effect go away sooner or later, and re-enabling the last property again does not revert it. It is also not always triggered by the same property.

Comment: @CBroe I did how you suggested, and played a lot with toggling different properties on-off, and what I experienced was that it is the background and border properties that cause the issue, but the browser's behavior is very unpredictable. There are no distinct properties removing which would make the select look normal, but there is an endless combination of those values that toggle the arrow's look between normal and ugly, so I decided to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24412) for more information.